# Identify a book about a boy with a magic mirror who becomes a scribe then wizard

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book about a boy that was on a farm and looks into a magic mirror. Later the boy becomes a scribe and eventually joins a wizard college.

He used magic in a sewer to hone his skills then at the end of the three books he becomes the main wizard.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [*The White Order*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_White_Order.html?id=YxVBPgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) one of the *Saga of Recluse* novels by L.E. Modesitt Jr.

This novel starts the story arc of Cerryl, a young orphan who has the powers of Chaos inside him.

The story follows him working as a mill boy, then an apprentice scrivener in Fairhaven until he is ordered to go to the White Tower, to learn to be a white mage.

The screening occurs early on when he finds a sliver of a mirror and scries a young girl (Leyladin).  He meets her in person later in the story.

One of the tasks of the student mages is to learn how to wield chaos effectively by cleaning the sewers of Fairhaven.

The sequel is *Colours of Chaos* and details Cerryl's rise to High Wizard of the White Order, and his struggles to reform the guild.

Comment: i have been looking for years! thank you soooo much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you know that one from memory, or search?

Comment: @fuzzyboots I knew the answer from memory.  The White characters like Lorn and Cerryl from the series are very memorable to me

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can click the accept arrow to mark my answer as the correct one.  This helps others on the site with similar questions